# Who owns the rights to 'Valentine the Dark Avenger'?

Tags: valentine-the-dark-avenger

Who owns the rights to Valentine the Dark Avenger?  The only Wikipedia reference I can find is the following [Dark Avengers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Avengers) listing which is definitely owned by Marvel.

It seems funny to me that it uses the name Avenger but it's not made by Disney owned Marvel.

To clarify I am asking who owns the rights to the character but if in scope also how they are able to use the word Avenger without potentially infringing copyright.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Worldwide character rights to 'Valentine' are held by [Skylar Comics](https://japanesestation.com/event-launching-komik-valentine/) and their film division [Skylar Pictures](http://www.skylarpictures.net). The character was an original comic creation of Skylar producers Sarjono Sutrisno and Aswin MC Siregar and artist Ian Waryanto. Note that despite the words "*Dark Avenger*" being included in the full *movie* title, the character (and studio) are in no way linked to "*The Avengers*", a character mark held by Marvel Comics.

> Valentine is the newest comic drama-action genre from Skylar Comics.
> The Valentine comic story idea emerged from Sarjono Sutrisno who was
> later developed by Aswin MC Siregar. The picture in this comic was
> entrusted to Ian Waryanto and the coloring by Warnia K. Sahadewa who
> had previously helped with the previous comic Skylar Comics project.
>
> <sub><sup>[Event Launching Comic “Valentine”  (in translation)](https://japanesestation.com/event-launching-komik-valentine/)</sup></sub>

[image]

---

**International distribution rights are jointly held by the producer of the new 2019 feature, [Shout! Studios](https://www.shoutfactory.com/corp/shout-studios-releases) and [Skylar Pictures](http://www.skylarpictures.net)**

[image]

UK, and presumably European,  distribution rights are held by [Carnaby International Film Sales & Distribution](http://www.carnabysales.com/).

> Fantasy action feature Valentine has scored a North America deal for UK sales outfit Carnaby International.
>
> Shout! Studios has picked up the title, which is from Indonesian production company Skylar Pictures.
>
> <sub>[Carnaby inks North America deal on Indonesian superhero film 'Valentine' (exclusive) - ScreenDaily](https://www.screendaily.com/news/carnaby-inks-north-america-deal-on-indonesian-superhero-film-valentine-exclusive/5136383.article)</sub>

Comment: How did the split up of the marvel characters occur such that skylar owns this specific character?

Comment: @William - AFAIK, the character is not a Marvel creation.

Comment: This leads me to believe it is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Avengers

Answer (score 4):

Disney/Marvel doesn't have the exclusive right to the name "Avenger" or even "Avengers" for action heroes. The British TV series *[The Avengers](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0054518/)* premiered in 1961, while Marvel's Avengers comic did not begin until 1963. In addition, there was a 1998 movie called *[The Avengers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118661)* based on the TV series. We can add the 2006 TV movie *[Avenger](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0473445)*, the 1984 movie *[The Toxic Avenger](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090190)*, the 1990 TV movie *[Dark Avenger](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099360)* and many more to realise that it is a very common word in titles, used even before Lee/Kirby created *The Avengeers*.

For this reason, Marvel/Disney would be in trouble for claiming trademark on "Avenger" or "Avengers". They can, however, trademark the Avengers logo (and have). Also, [Marvel has claimed trademark](https://trademarks.justia.com/863/38/avengers-86338494.html) for the word "Avengers" used in clothing and for [serial publications](https://trademark.trademarkia.com/the-avengers-72278015.html) featuring the word "Avengers".

Comment: Although, to be fair, DC and Marvel managed a stranglehold on "superhero" through sheer menace.

Comment: This answer doesn't really address the core question, that being "who owns Valentine the Dark Avenger?".

Comment: @Xantec - It answers the second portion of the question, which is how it's possible to use "Avenger" near a superhero without Marvel's lawyers setting up camp on your lawn